Creating interactive QGIS web map
I use QGIS, and want to build a locally hosted interactive web map displaying various proprietary and open data, that internal staff can search/query.
QGIS2Web looks to be suitable for most of these needs, but I would like users to be able to draw polygons and lines, calculate measurements and most importantly upload custom shapefiles to be overlaid with other data. Uploaded shapefiles don’t need to be stored on a server anywhere after the user is finished. However, the option to export any drawn geometry to shapefile on their PC would also be a huge bonus. I can't seem to find anything out of the box that does any of this, though.
What solution would be best to achieve a web map/app that can not only serve users with visualised data, but also be supplemented with uploaded user shapefiles?
Using ArcGIS Online is not an option.

The software recommendations stack exchange is probably better for this question, gis stack exchange tends to discourage opinion based questions.

I maintain qgis2web and have created an enhanced version called qgis2o.gis that can be obtained with a donation. This version integrates much more functionality, among there is already the ability to draw and measure.
Other features can be integrated, for example all those that are part of the ol-ext library, but they are to be configured.
Here is an example for loading shp into map:
How to display shapefiles on an OpenLayers web mapping application that are provided by users as an input without making any changes in the database
Here a library to transform what geojson draws into shpfile:
https://github.com/morganherlocker/geojson2shape

Thank you very much for the answer, this seems like a great solution to our needs!
